# pcolormesh quadrilateral alignment

Tags: python, matplotlib

Looking at the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.pcolormesh.html), `quadrilateral` should have X, Y coordinates on the lower-left corner, but I get them with X,Y as center point. How can I fix it? Everything seems to be shifted up and right by 0.5.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.arange(20)
Y = np.arange(11)
Z = [[11, 41, 77, 84, 45, 20, 9, 5, 2, 1, 1, 1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
      [np.nan, np.nan, 1, 46, 109, 87, 49, 26, 14, 8, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
      [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 2, 45, 97, 82, 50, 28, 16, 10, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, np.nan],
      [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 7, 53, 76, 57, 34, 20, 11, 7, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, np.nan],
      [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1, 17, 47, 46, 30, 17, 10, 6, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, np.nan, np.nan],
      [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 4, 21, 28, 20, 12, 6, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
      [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1, 7, 13, 11, 6, 3, 2, 1, 1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
      [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 2, 5, 5, 3, 1, 1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
      [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 2, 2, 1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
      [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]]


plt.figure()
plt.pcolormesh(X[1:], Y[1:], Z, cmap='jet')
plt.xlim([0, 1.5 * 8.3])
plt.ylim([0, 2 * 5])
plt.grid(True)
plt.colorbar()

plt.show()
```

This is what I get:

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `X[1:]` and `Y[1:]` instead of the entire arrays?

Comment: Take a look at the example https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/pcolormesh_levels.html#basic-pcolormesh and note that the `x` and `y` values contain one more value that the `z` array to define the bin edges.

Comment: As to the point made by @MattPitkin. `np.array(Z).shape → (10, 19)`. I appreciate the complete [mre]. Nicely done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the solution is to change your line:

```
plt.pcolormesh(X[1:], Y[1:], Z, cmap='jet')
```

to be

```
plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z, cmap='jet')
```

I.e., use the full `X` and `Y` arrays, which (due to being 1 larger than the respective `Z` dimensions) will define the bin edges.

Note that you could convert `X` and `Y` into 2D arrays, i.e.,

```
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
print(X.shape, Y.shape)
(11, 20) (11, 20)
```

and pass them to `pcolormesh`, although `pcolormesh` will do this itself internally if `X` and `Y` are only 1D arrays.

Comment: I got it! The thing is that I'm porting some code from MATLAB, and there indexing starts from 0, that's why I was confused, but now everything is clear, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.pcolormesh.html) closely, you'll see the issue. When you do not provide a `shading` argument, it defaults to `"auto"`. The documentation explains how `"auto"` works:

> Choose 'flat' if dimensions of X and Y are one larger than C. Choose 'nearest' if dimensions are the same.

Since you're indexing `X[1:]` and `Y[1:]`, your `X`, `Y`, and `Z` (`C`) dimensions all match, so `pcolormesh` uses the `"nearest"` shading method. When `"nearest"` is used

> Each grid point will have a color centered on it, extending halfway between the adjacent grid centers.

Hence, your cells are centered on the `(X,Y)` points.

To fix this, provide the entire `X` and `Y` arrays, which will result in the arrays being one larger than `Z`, triggering `shading="flat"` to be used, which uses `(X[i,j], Y[i,j])` for the bottom left coordinate.

Here is the result (I removed the axes limits and set the aspect ratio to 1).

[image]